# Python: Rotation not applying to child object

Tags: python, scripting, transforms, parent, command-line

I am trying to pose a hand using values read from an XML file. All the joints are parented to the previous joint and finally the fingers to the hand.
Í am using the following code:

```
#imports

bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=filepath)

#load xml etc

for joint in joint_rotations:
    object = bpy.data.objects[joint.name]]
    rot_mat = Matrix.Rotation(joint.rotation, 4, 'X')
    object.matrix_world @= rot_mat

bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=outfilepath)
```

The code works, when I execute it joint for joint by myself, and gives the expected result.
However, when I use a for loop to iterate over all elements, I get the wrong result where all elements rotate independently of their parent. Why would a for loop of the same instructions yield a different result than the instructions themselves?

[image: What I want: Parent transformation applied]

[image: What I get: Joint rotated independently]

Comment: Please correct the double bracket typo in your question.
object = bpy.data.objects[joint.name]]

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this problem is that changing the parent matrix does not update the child matrix while the script is running.
To fix this use: 
(1) Dependency graph or 
(2) matrix_local instead of matrix_world.

**Dependency graph**

```
dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()

for joint in joint_rotations:
    object = bpy.data.objects[joint.name]
    rot_mat = Matrix.Rotation(joint.rotation, 4, 'X')

    obj_eval = object.evaluated_get(dg)
    object.matrix_world = obj_eval.matrix_world @ rot_mat
    dg.update()
```

**matrix_local**

```
for joint in joint_rotations:
    object = bpy.data.objects[joint.name]
    rot_mat = Matrix.Rotation(joint.rotation, 4, 'X')

    # Investigating.: for some reason this code doesn't work. 
    #object.matrix_local @= rot_mat 
    object.matrix_local = object.matrix_local @ rot_mat
```